# Property 'getCurrentNavigation' does not exist on type 'Router' in angular 6

Tags: angular6, router

Retrieving the state value:

```
import { Router,NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router'; 
constructor(private router: Router)
{   
   const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
   const state = navigation.extras.state as {example: string};
   this.example = state.example;
}
```

Route Navigation

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state: {example: 'This is an example'}};
  this.router.navigate(['/trace/geospatial'], navigationExtras);
```

I get the following error:

> Property 'getCurrentNavigation' does not exist on type 'Router' and Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Angular 7.2](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) and above to use the `router.getCurrentNavigation()` method.